# Sum values until next blank in a column (variable number between each blank), then repeat process for each set between blanks

Tags: excel

Essentially what I would like to do is sum up the values of some cells in a column (D) until the next blank in the column (D), while reporting the totals in  columns (F) and (G) in line with the identifier in column (B). The blanks in column (D) line up with the identifiers in column (B). The attached image shows the example data that I am working with.

From the example data what I want to do is report the total emails from each individual email for sent (column D) and received (column E) for each salesperson (column B). I need this total to be generated in the highlighted cells in columns F and G in line with the Salesperson identifier in column B.

[image: Example Sheet]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I believe this will require @ScottCraner

Comment: Does it have to be this format? A pivot table could be used after a few tweaks to the table, which I believe would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F2 put:

```
=IF($B2<>"",SUM(D2:D$1040000)-SUM(F3:F$1040000),"")
```

Copy over one column and down the data set.  The correct answer will not appear till you fill the column with the formula down the data set as it relies on the data beneath it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott! This worked perfectly and makes a ton of sense, thank you for your help and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting alternative which does not rely upon the result of the formulas below:

```
=IF(D3<>"","",SUMPRODUCT(D4:D27*(ROW(D4:D27)<MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(ISBLANK(D4:D27), 0, 0), 0)+ROW(D3))))
```

[image]

Comment: A slightly shorter version of your array formula: `=IF($B3<>"",SUM(D3:INDEX(D4:D$27,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B4:$B$27<>"",),0))),"")`

Comment: But being an array formula it must be confined to the data set references and a column full of these will slow down the calcs.  which is why I went with the non array version

Comment: @ScottCraner Mine is not an array formula... or at least in as much as you do not need to enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: It may not need to be entered with CSE, but it is an array formula.  The INDEX must iterate to return an array of `TRUE`/`FALSE`.  SUMPRODUCT is also an array formula, even though it does not require the use of CSE.  It's Nature is to iterate through the ranges.